# How to stochastically pick a binary state vector

Tags: machine-learning, probability

I'm trying to reproduce results of paper [Using Very Deep Auto encoders for
Content-Based Image Retrieval](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fritz/absps/esann-deep-final.pdf)

I have some working code thanks to Theano framework, but I don't really know what is meant by the first step in their algorithm:

For each data-vector, **v**, in a mini-batch, *stochastically pick a binary state
vector*, h for the hidden units:

[image: probability equation]

where `bj` is the bias, `wij`, is a weight, and `sigma(x) = (1 + exp(-x))^-1`.

I understand all parts of the equation. The only problem is how do I stochastically pick a binary state vector, given I know the probability of each element?

My idea is that for each element I generate random number, and if the number if higher than the probability, I will choose 1, otherwise 0. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Your solution is the intended one.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it already consists solution.